No support for egress XDP
why XDP egress is not supported ?
My understanding is that XDP is not supported by all NIC and NIC drivers in Linux kernel .
Hypothetically:(native XDP)
If there is xdp egress and we modify packet and add xdp_metadata while sending it Then at the receiver end an NIC receives a this packet and there will be ethernet frame checksum and this receiver NIC does not support xdp . So it will consider this packet as corrupted and will not accept the packet ?
IS this the reason that xdp need to be supported by every nic which would be a lot of work to do and most of the feature tc already gives that is why xdp egress is not there ?
can anyone add something to this . where I am getting wrong .

I think the reason XDP isn't supported on egress is that there isn't a use case for it. Why do you want XDP on egress given tc exists?
